# Low poly model showing on normal map in cycles, and normal map not showing on model in eevee

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, normal-map

Title says it all. Both things are shown underneath, ive been trying to fix this for about 2 hours now and im on verge of giving up.

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It got fixed by itself. Seems like it was the software bugging. Thanks either way.